# (Vega 64) amdgpu driver unloading

Tags: drivers, graphics, amdgpu

I need someone's help in getting my amdgpu driver working properly.

Long time Ubuntu user, but I'm not technical.  I have been wrecking my brain for the past 2 days, searching through an endless web.

Long story short:  I recently swapped my video card from an AMD HD-6950 (radeon) to an AMD Vega 64 (amdgpu).  I really should have been better about backups...

Ubuntu 18.04 + HWE (low-latency kernel 14.18.06) + padoka-stable.

This machine is more of a media workstation, (music production, image editing, video editing, etc.), but sometimes gaming.

I first physically installed the new card (with no software changes), and it seemed to perform worse. Due to the nature of the work, I decided to install amdgpu-pro drivers. They initially failed, and the system would not boot (black screen after grub).  Reinstalled under kernel 4.15, and it worked.

However, the performance was fairly poor, and some applications failed (eg. Kdenlive's video preview was all gray).  So I decided to uninstall amdgpu-pro, using AMD's uninstall utility.

But 4.18 was still borked.  I have no idea what I did.  Eventually, I had lots of accidental uninstalls and reinstalls; but at some point, I got it working with great gaming performance, using the amdgpu drivers (confirmed by inxi).  I think this was the result of a dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg.

However, because I wanted (in particular) openCL, and openCL was not included in amdgpu (confirmed in darktable), I decided to try Rocm, outlined here:
https://rocm.github.io/ROCmInstall.html

Broke the system again--and seemingly worse.

Now after a lot of fiddling, I can boot fine in any kernel (without requiring nomodeset); but inxi reports that it is using the fbdev & ati driver rather than amdgpu (as it was showing before).

I've poured through logs, made config changes, alternated packages, etc. and I cannot figure this out.

Here's where I am today:
-I can run & boot any kernel (4.15, 4.18, or 4.20)

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="radeon.si_support=0 radeon.cik_support=0 amdgpu.si_support=1 amdgpu.cik_support=1"
```

(^ this worked before. I've also tried amdgpu.dc=0, but that results in blackscreen hang).

/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-amdgpu.conf:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "AMDGPU"
    Driver "amdgpu"
    Option "AccelMethod" "glamor"
    Option "DRI" "3" 
    Option "TearFree" "true"
Endsection
```

^ This also worked before, and it appears to be picked up fine, according to the xorg logs.

lspci shows:

```
Subsystem: Sapphire Technology Limited Vega 10 XT [Radeon RX Vega 64]
Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
Kernel modules: amdgpu
```

But...the results of inxi -GC:

```
Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.20.1 )
drivers: fbdev,ati (unloaded: modesetting,vesa,radeon,amdgpu)
OpenGL: renderer: Radeon RX Vega (VEGA10, DRM 3.27.0, 4.20.17-042017-lowlatency, LLVM 8.0.0)
version: 4.5 Mesa 19.0.1 - padoka PPA
```

Previously, this ^ showed the driver as being amdgpu, rather than fbdev,ati.  And performance was noticeably different.

Also worth noting, dmesg doesn't appear to show any amdgpu unloading any more (though it previously did), and my xorg logs in /var/log appear not to be updating.  The ones in my ~ do appear to be updating though.

Also, I think I'm now on the hwe-18.04 packages (example for xserver-xorg, etc.)

Can someone help me get to a stable system, that's completely using amdgpu?  And ideally some hardware acceleration, including OpenCL?  And ideally, open source / repository so that future software update will seamlessly take care of further hardware acceleration?

I hope I am just an idiot and there is a simple fix or reinstall.

What information can I provide?

I am very, very thankful for any help you can give me!  This has really been stressing me out!

More info:  In case it helps:

```
dmesg | grep amdgpu
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-16-lowlatency root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root ro radeon.si_support=0 radeon.cik_support=0 amdgpu.si_support=1 amdgpu.cik_support=1 quiet splash vt.handoff=1
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-16-lowlatency root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root ro radeon.si_support=0 radeon.cik_support=0 amdgpu.si_support=1 amdgpu.cik_support=1 quiet splash vt.handoff=1
[    7.281446] [drm] amdgpu kernel modesetting enabled.
[    7.349423] fb: switching to amdgpudrmfb from VESA VGA
[    7.362715] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: Invalid PCI ROM header signature: expecting 0xaa55, got 0xffff
[    7.363410] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: VRAM: 8176M 0x000000F400000000 - 0x000000F5FEFFFFFF (8176M used)
[    7.363412] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: GTT: 512M 0x000000F600000000 - 0x000000F61FFFFFFF
[    7.364014] [drm] amdgpu: 8176M of VRAM memory ready
[    7.364016] [drm] amdgpu: 8176M of GTT memory ready.
[    7.806093] fbcon: amdgpudrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    7.806202] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: fb0: amdgpudrmfb frame buffer device
[    7.817102] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: ring 0(gfx) uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 0
[    7.817104] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: ring 1(comp_1.0.0) uses VM inv eng 5 on hub 0
[    7.817106] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: ring 2(comp_1.1.0) uses VM inv eng 6 on hub 0
[    7.817107] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: ring 3(comp_1.2.0) uses VM inv eng 7 on hub 0
[    7.817108] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: ring 4(comp_1.3.0) uses VM inv eng 8 on hub 0
[    7.817110] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: ring 5(comp_1.0.1) uses VM inv eng 9 on hub 0
[    7.817111] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: ring 6(comp_1.1.1) uses VM inv eng 10 on hub 0
[    7.817112] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: ring 7(comp_1.2.1) uses VM inv eng 11 on hub 0
[    7.817113] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: ring 8(comp_1.3.1) uses VM inv eng 12 on hub 0
[    7.817115] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: ring 9(kiq_2.1.0) uses VM inv eng 13 on hub 0
[    7.817116] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: ring 10(sdma0) uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 1
[    7.817117] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: ring 11(sdma1) uses VM inv eng 5 on hub 1
[    7.817118] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: ring 12(uvd<0>) uses VM inv eng 6 on hub 1
[    7.817120] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: ring 13(uvd_enc0<0>) uses VM inv eng 7 on hub 1
[    7.817121] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: ring 14(uvd_enc1<0>) uses VM inv eng 8 on hub 1
[    7.817122] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: ring 15(vce0) uses VM inv eng 9 on hub 1
[    7.817123] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: ring 16(vce1) uses VM inv eng 10 on hub 1
[    7.817124] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: ring 17(vce2) uses VM inv eng 11 on hub 1
[    7.817735] [drm] Initialized amdgpu 3.26.0 20150101 for 0000:07:00.0 on minor 0
```

And more:

```
   grep "amdgpu\|AMDGPU" Xorg.1.log
[    16.195] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-16-lowlatency root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root ro radeon.si_support=0 radeon.cik_support=0 amdgpu.si_support=1 amdgpu.cik_support=1 quiet splash vt.handoff=1
[    16.196] (**) |   |-->Device "AMDGPU"
[    16.196] (**) |   |-->GPUDevice "AMDGPU"
[    16.206] (II) LoadModule: "amdgpu"
[    16.206] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/amdgpu_drv.so
[    16.206] (II) Module amdgpu: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    16.207] (II) AMDGPU: Driver for AMD Radeon:
    All GPUs supported by the amdgpu kernel driver
[    16.207] (II) AMDGPU(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
[    16.207] (==) AMDGPU(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[    16.207] (II) AMDGPU(0): Pixel depth = 24 bits stored in 4 bytes (32 bpp pixmaps)
[    16.207] (==) AMDGPU(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    16.207] (**) AMDGPU(0): Option "AccelMethod" "glamor"
[    16.207] (**) AMDGPU(0): Option "DRI" "3"
[    16.207] (**) AMDGPU(0): Option "TearFree" "true"
[    16.207] (==) AMDGPU(0): RGB weight 888
[    16.207] (II) AMDGPU(0): Using 8 bits per RGB (8 bit DAC)
[    16.207] (--) AMDGPU(0): Chipset: "Radeon RX Vega" (ChipID = 0x687f)
[    16.293] (II) AMDGPU(0): glamor X acceleration enabled on Radeon RX Vega (VEGA10, DRM 3.26.0, 4.18.0-16-lowlatency, LLVM 9.0.0)
[    16.293] (II) AMDGPU(0): glamor detected, initialising EGL layer.
[    16.294] (**) AMDGPU(0): TearFree property default: on
[    16.294] (II) AMDGPU(0): KMS Pageflipping: enabled
[    16.294] (II) AMDGPU(0): Output DisplayPort-0 has no monitor section
[    16.294] (II) AMDGPU(0): Output DisplayPort-1 has no monitor section
[    16.294] (II) AMDGPU(0): Output HDMI-A-0 has no monitor section
[    16.294] (II) AMDGPU(0): Output HDMI-A-1 has no monitor section
[    16.303] (II) AMDGPU(0): EDID for output DisplayPort-0
[    16.303] (II) AMDGPU(0): EDID for output DisplayPort-1
[    16.304] (II) AMDGPU(0): EDID for output HDMI-A-0
[    16.304] (II) AMDGPU(0): Manufacturer: AOC  Model: 2757  Serial#: 1291
[    16.304] (II) AMDGPU(0): Year: 2013  Week: 42
[    16.304] (II) AMDGPU(0): EDID Version: 1.3
[    16.305] (II) AMDGPU(0): Digital Display Input
[    16.305] (II) AMDGPU(0): Max Image Size [cm]: horiz.: 60  vert.: 34
[    16.305] (II) AMDGPU(0): Gamma: 2.20
[    16.305] (II) AMDGPU(0): DPMS capabilities: Off
[    16.305] (II) AMDGPU(0): Supported color encodings: RGB 4:4:4 YCrCb 4:4:4 
[    16.305] (II) AMDGPU(0): First detailed timing is preferred mode
[    16.305] (II) AMDGPU(0): redX: 0.640 redY: 0.338   greenX: 0.315 greenY: 0.623
[    16.305] (II) AMDGPU(0): blueX: 0.151 blueY: 0.063   whiteX: 0.313 whiteY: 0.329
[    16.305] (II) AMDGPU(0): Supported established timings:
[    16.305] (II) AMDGPU(0): 720x400@70Hz
```

(then a bunch of monitor modes)

Answer (score 0):

I unfortunately didn't get any replies to my question, but I was finally able to get things working.

In case this is useful to someone, I went through my apt logs to find every package that changed over the course of this ordeal.  One that was missing was compiz-plugins.  I also did a reinstall of many packages.

Finally, I ran

```
sudo X -configure
```

To reconfigure X.  I was previously running something like:
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg`
(or potentially with the hwe version)
but it wasn't giving me any response after running.  I didn't realize this may have meant that it didn't do anything.

Not sure how, but this combination of reinstalling packages & reconfiguring X worked.